# I can't open other partition in my PC

Tags: system-settings

When I try to open another partition in my PC, it shows this error message:

[image: error message]

How can I fix this error??

(Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 1):

Windows saves hibernation data in any NTFS drives you mount, even if you haven't hibernated Windows. The recommendation to fix the issue is to make sure you fully shut down your computer after using Windows, but that doesn't generally work.

Instead, use `ntfsfix`.

In case it isn't installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Then:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3
```

That should let you mount it.

Comment: it was not worked..

Comment: @EshanMalimbada in what way?

Comment: i can't open it yet.

Comment: i have a screen shot of error massage.