# Some time NTFS partitions can't open in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10. When I try to open my other partition (NTFS), sometimes I can open it. But sometimes I can't open it. 
It shows this error message:

[image]

I asked this question in this site. ([I can't open other partition in my PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829053/i-cant-open-other-partition-in-my-pc))
And I followed that solutions. it did not work.

After that I followed other solution. ([Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation))
But I can't understand those solution.

How do I fix my pc?

Answer (score 2):

You have to boot into Windows, disable fastboot and do a prober shutdown.
Then boot into Ubuntu again, and you will be able to mount the NTFS partiton.

Exactly at the error message says.

Comment: I just can't open windows 10. Because it not boot. (some virus attack).

Comment: I just can't open windows 10. Because it not boot (some virus attack). i will format windows 10.  I try to backup my files before format windows 10.  i want to fix it through Ubuntu..

Comment: Then read the part, in your link number 2, about ntfsfix .. and use that to fix your problem.

Comment: yes i done it.  it worked. but i can't open C partition.

Comment: What C partition .. Doesn't 'ntfsfix /ddev/sda3' work ? Then maybe your disk / partiton is broken. Please edit your question with the output from the command.

Comment: terminal :- eshan@eshan-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2
[sudo] password for eshan: 
Mounting volume... Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted
eshan@eshan-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK:

Comment: Then you have to get Windows working to fix it ... sorry.

Comment: i can't boot windows. i need to copy some files (downloads , document..) before formatting windows. if i format windows, it will be deleted  . what i do it??